# Encrypted site and header location redirect

Tags: redirect, https, header

I have recently encrypted a site for a client and am finding some people get insecure site warning in Chrome with the triangle icon.

My major problem tho is that the contact form php processor has a:

```
header('location:https://www.bioloo.co.nz/index.php/thanks');
```

but viewers get the warning instead of to the Thank You page. My webhost reports the certificate is valid and all absolute urls are set properly.

Do I have to set a no-cache tag?

Any ideas please?

Comment: How recently did you acquire the cert? It takes a while for it to properly 'propagate'. It's likely a caching issue, which is set on individual pages.

Comment: It was encrypted yesterday morning. Webhost has checked on PC and phone and it shows fine. weird that the client has problems. He is linking from Google AdWords so maybe the url is wrong?